# WPF beginner: How to bind to an instance of a class and reference it in code-behind event handlers

Tags: c#, wpf

Trying to learn WPF. Struggling with data-binding setup. On my main UI, I have two comboboxes linked to properties of the instance class. I want to 'reuse' that class instance in event handlers.

My struggle isn't with getting the code working, but of a design best-practices nature.

My class (simplified)

```
public class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SomeClass() {}

    public IList<string> Categories
    {
        get
        {
            return _categories;
        }
        set
        {
            _categories = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Categories));
        }
    }

    public IList<string> Forms
    {
        get
        {
            return _forms;
        }
        set
        {
            _forms = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Forms));
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

My first instinct was to declare all the bindings in the xaml. Everything in one place. Something like

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:SomeClass x:key="MyClass"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then in a toolbar:

```
<ToolBarPanel x:Name="myToolStripName" DataContext="{StaticResource MyClass}">
    <ToolBarTray>
        <ToolBar Height="25px">
            <ComboBox x:Name="cboCategories"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Categories}"
                      SelectionChanged="CboCategories_SelectionChanged" />
            <ComboBox x:Name="cboForms"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Forms}" />
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
</ToolBarPanel>
```

In the code-behind of `MainWindow` there is the event handler

```
private void CboCategories_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string categoryName = e.AddedItems[0].ToString();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryName))
    {
        [problem: MyClass/SomeClass].GetFormNames(categoryName);
    }
}
```

I run into trouble here. I need to call a method in my instance class, but I do not think I can get to it from the event handler. Can I? I could simply new it up, but I would loose the binding.

So this approach isn't going to work. I could change my `SomeClass` to be a Singleton, but I read those are considered an anti-pattern. Another approach would be to make it `static`, but then I cannot (easily) implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

In the end, I made `SomeClass` a `private readonly` field of `MainWindow.xaml.cs` and set the `DataContext` from there. Which works fine, but now the application relies on bindings being defined in both the xaml and code-behind, which feels counter-intuitive. I could of course move all the databinding stuff to code-behind. Again, counter-intuitive.

Given the setup described, which I feel must be really common, can you please give me some guidance on what is considered best-practice and suggestions for improvement?

Comment: Are you trying to use `MVVM`?

Comment: If yes you don't have to write `events` on code behind check `ICommand` once

Comment: No. This is just a quick-and-dirty trying to get something to work thing. I am sort of familiar with MVVM in ASP.NET but never tried WPF before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach would be to assign the view model `SomeClass` to the `Window.DataContext` instead of `Window.Resources` and use the property inheritance feature of `DataContext`:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:SomeClass x:Name="ViewModel"/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Remove the `DataContext` property declaration from the `ToolBarPanel` since the `DataContext` is inherited from the parent element (the `Window`). All child elements of a `FrameworkElement` in the visual tree will inherit their parent's `DataContext`:

```
<ToolBarPanel x:Name="MyToolStripName">
    <ToolBarTray>
        <ToolBar Height="25px">
            <ComboBox x:Name="CboCategories"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
                      SelectionChanged="CboCategories_SelectionChanged" />
            <ComboBox x:Name="CboForms"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Forms}" />
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
</ToolBarPanel>
```

In your event handler just cast the `DataContext` from `Object` to your view model `SomeClass`:

```
private void CboCategories_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var categoryName = e.AddedItems[0].ToString();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryName)
        && this.DataContext is SomeClass viewModel)
    {
        viewModel.GetFormNames(categoryName);
    }
}
```

If want to get rid of the event handler in the code-behind file, given that it doesn't do UI related operations, you can add a property as binding target for `SelectedItem` to the view model:

```
public class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string selectedCategory;
    public string SelectedCategory
    {
        get => this.selectedCategory;
        set
        {
            this.selectedCategory = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            GetFormNames(this.SelectedCategory);
        }
    }     

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }  

    ...
}
```

Replace the event handler with the binding of `SelectedItem` to the view model. The `Binding.Mode` has to be set to either `OneWayToSource` or `TwoWay` in order to send the data to the binding source:

```
<ToolBarPanel x:Name="MyToolStripName">
    <ToolBarTray>
        <ToolBar Height="25px">
            <ComboBox x:Name="CboCategories"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <ComboBox x:Name="CboForms"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Forms}" />
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
</ToolBarPanel>
```

Applying the attribute [[`CallerMemberName`]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) to your PropertyChanged invocator method's parameter, like in the example, makes invocations more convenient since you do not have to pass the property names anymore.

Comment: Looks promising, will muck about with my code and get back to this question. Thanks.

Comment: BionicCode: Just a heads up: your answer was very helpful. Would never have figured out how to get the model instance from the datacontext. In the end I went the model way, combing several models into a parent composite model for I needed several because different UI elements listen to different models, like a StatusBar etc.